# How do I use codeigniter in a subfolder on a server?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have two codeigniter installations under my public_html folder on my  server. One is directly under public_html and the other is under public_html/posts_receive.

The instance under public_html is working normal but when I try to access the codeigniter controller inside public_html/posts_receive it shows:

> 404 Page Not Found
>
> tried url http://www.example.com/posts_receive/index.php/dashboard

To solve this problem I have added an `.htaccess` file under public_html/posts_receive which contain the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /posts_receive
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

My controller is named **dashboard.php** and contains the following:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Dashboard extends CI_Controller {


    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

        $this->load->library("pagination");
    }

    public function index() {
        $config = array();

        $data['link_sel']='dashboard';
        $data['stats']=$this->fetch_stats();
        $this->load->view("header_inc", $data);
        $this->load->view("dashboard", $data);
        $this->load->view("footer_inc", $data);
    }   
}
?>
```

**config.php** includes:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.example.com/posts_receive/';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

Comment: Did you try `http://www.example.com/posts_receive/dashboard` ? can you post the outcome of this?

Comment: Ya i tried the same it showing the same error,no changes

Comment: is it the same thing even when you remove the htaccess?

Comment: Beginning itself it shows the error as file not found.I referred some guide.So i added .htaccess. But again it showing the same error.

Answer (score 2):

You should run both applications from one CodeIgniter base. You will have 2 sub folders in your `application` folder.  Take a look at the documentation: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/managing_apps.html

From there on you can create the same index.php file as in your root in your `posts_recieve` folder and point it to the right application directory. That is how i managed to do it. Otherwise the CodeIgniter instance in your root will think you are navigating to a controller called `posts_recieve` which does not exists in that application.Hope this helps. Otherwise, just ask when things are unclear.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But i need to use these in separate folder.

Comment: You need 2 seperate (and thus duplicate) system folders? Why though. Why not run both from the same CodeIgniter Core and split them in 2 application folders?

Answer (score 0):

Inside **.htaccess**, `RewriteBase /posts_receive` part is not needed.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
```

should become

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

(`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` is a server configuration condition. It means you should have **mod_rewrite** module installed and active on the web server for these settings to work.)

You could leave empty `$config['index_page']` inside **config.php**:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

And you can call the controller without the **index.php** part:

```
http://www.example.com/posts_receive/dashboard
```